# Reference an entity with a formula in Fluent NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a schema with an `N:1` parent-child relationship that is stored in another table and is selected by a formula. Is it possible to map this entity to the parent using a formula?

```
public class ParentEntity {
    public virtual int ParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual ChildEntity Child{ get; set; }
}


public class ParentMapping : ClassMap<ParentEntity> {
    public ParentMapping() {
        Table("ParentTable");

        Id(x => x.ParentId).Column("ParentId").GeneratedBy.Assigned().Not.Nullable();
        References<ChildEntity>(x => x.Child).Formula(
            @"(
                SELECT TOP 1 ChildTable.ChildId
                FROM ChildTable
                WHERE ChildTable.ParentId = ParentId
            )"
        );
    }
}
```

The SQL that this mapping generates looks like this:

```
SELECT
    this_.ParentId,
    this_.ChildEntity_id
FROM ParentTable this_
```

This is not what I'm looking for.

How can I reference this child entity and use, instead of `ChildId` in the parent table, a formula that selects `ChildId` from a formula?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*I won't anyhow discuss the correctness of this approach, just try to answer.* What you are trying to do:  **should** work. I've checked the correctness of the formula in a test scenario. So, yes formula could be used exactly this way.

But because it is not working, I would a bit guess. Let's start with SQL generated in my test case, which is working.

```
SELECT this_.ParentId as ParentId3_0_
, (SELECT TOP 1 Child.ChildId
     FROM Child
     WHERE Child.ParentId = this_.ParentId) as formula1_0_ 
FROM Parent this_
```

### Possible issues

I see two possible issues

#### 1. Different Child ID column names

First of all in your snippet:

```
References<ChildEntity>(x => x.Child).Formula(
            @"(
                SELECT TOP 1 ChildTable.ChildId
                FROM ChildTable
                WHERE ChildTable.ParentId = ParentId
            )"
```

is column name of child primary key: **`ChildId`** while in SQL snippet is the **`ChildEntity_id`**:

```
SELECT
    this_.ParentId,
    this_.ChildEntity_id
FROM ParentTable this_
```

#### 2. SQL Snippet does not match

Secondly, you mentioned that the (SQL Statement just above) is what was generated. But it is more like a statement of this mapping:

```
References<ChildEntity>(x => x.Child).Column("ChildEntity_id")
```

So couldn't be there some older/other mapping, which is in fact used?

SUMMARY
I wanted to say, that this way of mapping is working. So you are on the correct track, but *the devil is hidden in details* ;)